# SQL - NOT LIKE and LIKE with only characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL(without concrete implementation).

I need to validate that some value contains only characters using **LIKE** or **NOT LIKE**

**1**.Incorrect example is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]'
```

because '*123A123*' would be *true*

**2**. I read up that It would work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

These queries look equal to me(It's like to compare 5 and --5)

Could you explain please what is the difference between?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Superficially, alphabetic letters are different from numbers, but I don't think that is what you are asking about.

Comment: I am asking why WHERE name NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%' and name LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]'  are not the same

Comment: question has been edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's dissect this:

```
NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

The regexp here is "does not contain any letters". If we negate using `NOT LIKE`, it'll mean "contains only letters".

Now:

```
name LIKE '%[A-Za-z]%'
```

Regexp here means "contains at least one letter". So `LIKE` on that will mean the same thing.

So:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A123'), ('123'), ('AAA'), (',')) x(name)
WHERE name LIKE'%[A-Za-z]%'
```

This will return both `A123` (there's an A) and `AAA`, but neither `123` (only digits) nor `,` (still not a letter) will get returned.

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('A123'), ('123'), ('AAA'), (',')) x(name)
WHERE name NOT LIKE '%[^A-Za-z]%'
```

This one will only return `AAA` because it's the only one containing letters only. `AAA` is the only record that regexp will not match, and since we're negating with `NOT LIKE`, it means only this one meets the `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 1):

This expression:

```
WHERE name NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'
```

matches all names that have a character that is not a letter, such as `.` or `;` or whatever.

This expression:

```
 name LIKE '%[a-zA-Z]'
```

matches all names that contain at least *one* letter.

So, `'ABC.DEF'` will match both patterns -- it matches the first because it has `.` and the second because it has a letter.

However, `'ABC'` does *not* match the first pattern because it only consists of letters.  It does match the second one.

Comment: Uhm, I think you messed that up a bit. ABC totally matches `NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'`. `NOT` negates the pattern. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6cb834f54e5647985bdf7c3cc38d14ff).

Answer (score 0):

Following condition will check whether your column value has any string character from a-z or A-Z in it.

```
where name NOT REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]'
```